# Providing a seed when using the random generator in java?

Tags: java, random

How do you provide a seed for a java random generator?
Random generator = new Random(2002334);
Does this produce the same number every time the random generator is called and does it matter what number you use as a seed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating an instance of the [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.

```
Random rand = new Random(42);
int x = rand.nextInt(); // will always be the same
```

You can also use the [setSeed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed%28long%29) method to (re-)set the seed on an already created Random instance:

```
rand.setSeed(42);
int x = rand.nextInt(); // will be the same again
```

Comment: and will those values be positive or will i have to use math.abs?

Comment: no, they will be positive, negative or (with a very small likelihood) exactly 0. But there is also nextInt(int max) which returns an integer between 0 and one smaller than the maximum value you specify.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random(long seed)
```

- Creates a new random number generator using a single long seed:

from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Use the constructor as `Random random = new Random(seedValue);` //<--Pass the desired seed value as argument
2. Use the `setSeed` method as `random.setSeed(seedValue);` to set the desired seed value after instantiation.

You may refer the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long)